# Number of one one functions with no fixed points.

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-groups

Let $f:A \to A$ be a function from a set $A$ with $n$ elements. How many $f$ are there which are bijective and satisfies the property $f(a)\neq a$ for any $a \in A$ ?

Comment: There are $n!$ bijections $A\to A$. Maybe you can count all bijections with a given fixpoint? Then you only have to ensure that you count bijections with any fixpoint the right way...

Comment: for $n=3$ $A=\{a,b,c\}$, there are $3!=6$ bijections. There are $2!=2$ bijections fixing $a$, there are 2 bijections fixing $b$, there are $2$ bijections fixing $c$. Those are $6$ bijections, but we double-counted some. There is one bijection fixing two elements (the identity), so we end up with 4 bijections with fixpoints. So there are 2 bijections left which have no fixpoints.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement